# Empty cursor and exception

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, cursor

I was trying to get exception just to see how it works.I declare a cursor which is fetching no data from the table because as per my where clause there is no salary more than 60000. Cursor should be empty? I tried two method to get the error message but I got message like 'anonymous block completed'.

```
set serverout ON
declare
c_empid kt_test.empid%type;

cursor c_kt is select empid into c_empid from kt_test where salary > 60000;

BEGIN
  open c_kt;

  fetch c_kt into c_empid;
exception
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001,'Data not found for employee');
  close c_kt;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Other error-'||SQLCODE||'-'||SQLERRM);
end;
```

And

```
set serverout ON
declare
c_empid kt_test.empid%type;

cursor c_kt is select empid into c_empid from kt_test where salary > 60000;

BEGIN
  open c_kt;

  fetch c_kt into c_empid;
  IF c_kt%NOTFOUND THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Explicit Cursor: No data found');
    END IF;
END;

line 1: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set serverout ON
anonymous block completed
```

What is missing here so that I would get the error message?

Comment: You need `set serveroutPUT ON`

Comment: @Aleksej I did correction. But first code still not working.Just completing with the message 'anonymous block completed'.

Comment: What did you expect instead? If there is at least one row in the table that matches your filter, this will not print anything.

Comment: I the kt_test table, there is no record having salary more than 60000. I just want to use no_data_found exception with the cursor. Is it possible?

Comment: With cursor - no.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple working example:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2      cursor c is select 1 from dual where 1 = 0;
  3      vN  number;
  4  begin
  5      open c;
  6      fetch c into vN;
  7
  8      if c%NOTFOUND then
  9          dbms_output.put_line('No data');
 10      end if;
 11  end;
 12  /
No data

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this variant (slightly modified):

```
set serveroutput ON
declare
  c_empid kt_test.empid%type;

  cursor c_kt is 
  select empid
  from kt_test 
  where salary > 60000;

BEGIN
  open c_kt;
  fetch c_kt into c_empid;
  close c_kt;

  IF c_empid is null THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Explicit Cursor: No data found');
  END IF;
END;
```

When run in anonymous block in pl/sql developer, output: "Explicit Cursor: No data found"

If you want, that first code segment would work, you need to rewrite it like this:

```
declare
  c_empid number;

BEGIN

  select empid 
  into c_empid
  from kt_test
  where salary > 60000;  

exception
  when no_data_found then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Insert into: No data found');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use your own defined error message.

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  custom_err EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( custom_err, -20001 );
  CURSOR c
  IS
    SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE 1 = 0;
  vN NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN c;
  FETCH c INTO vN;
  IF c%NOTFOUND THEN
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'This is a custom error' );
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN custom_err THEN
  dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
END;
```

Comment: I got the output:   anonymous block completed
ORA-20001: This is a custom error                                                                                    so what is the use of   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( custom_err, -20001 ), Can you please explain in brief.